# How to split string into multiple rows in a table using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Four different columns. Its called Box Table. It contains characteristics of different boxes.

Following are the names of the columns: Serial Number, Box Height, Box Width, Box Weight.

The first column (Serial Number) is a string, but it can contain multiple boxes in a single row e.g: (212,234). If a string contains multiples boxes, I want to split that string into different rows (the number of boxes, determined by number of commas + 1). When I do this, I want other column values to replicate for the newly created row(s) as well. e.g

```
Serial Number: 1,2 | Box Height: 5 | Box Width: 2 | Box Weight: 100
```

After transformation:

```
Row (1): Serial Number: 1 | Box Height: 5 | Box Width: 2 | Box Weight: 100
Row (2): Serial Number: 2 | Box Height: 5 | Box Width: 2 | Box Weight: 100
```

I cannot understand how to even begin this problem. The most I can do is remove the special characters from the string.

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One typical solution is to generate a list of numbers (by creating a table or using an inline query) and then `JOIN` it with the source data, using MySQL string functions to extract the relevant parts of `serial_number`.

Here is a solution that uses an inline query and that can handle up to 5 serials per record (to handle more serials, you would need to expand the subquery with more `UNION ALL`s):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(box.serial_number, ',', num.n), 
        ',', 
        -1
    ) new_serial_number,
    box.height,
    box.width,
    box.weight
FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 n
        UNION ALL SELECT 2
        UNION ALL SELECT 3
        UNION ALL SELECT 4
        UNION ALL SELECT 5
    ) num
    INNER JOIN box 
        ON CHAR_LENGTH(box.serial_number) 
               - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(box.serial_number, ',', '')) 
           >= num.n - 1
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gArUvAPJCqeYTujjFo5GKt/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| new_serial_number | height | width | weight |
| ----------------- | ------ | ----- | ------ |
| 1                 | 5      | 2     | 100    |
| 2                 | 5      | 2     | 100    |
```